# How to listen on udp port for not local traffic?

Tags: go, udp

I have simple udp service in Go, but it listens only for packets generated on the local server (where my udp service is started). If packets are coming from outside , they don't reach my udp service.

```
func ListenUDP(syslog string) (*net.UDPConn) {
    udpAddr, _ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", syslog)        
    ln, _ := net.ListenUDP("udp", udpAddr)
    return ln    
}

func Start(conn *net.UDPConn) []byte {    
    buffer := make([]byte, 2048)
    n, _, _ := conn.ReadFromUDP(buffer)
    return (buffer[:n])
}

ln, _ := syslogd.ListenUDP("0.0.0.0:12514")
data := syslogd.Start(ln)
```

And I verified that packets are not blocked by local firewall or iptables

Comment: How have you verified that the packets are not blocked? Do you have a pcap showing the packets arriving on port 12514? You're checking the Listen or Read error; are there any errors?

Comment: removed err from code snippet, but they are in actual code and not showing anything. I am running tcpdump and getting '15:59:09.388942 IP 10.199.107.10.60569 > 10.29.21.200.12514: UDP, length 384' a lot of packets. My iptable is 'ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0'

Comment: did you verify that you don't have another process listening for packets on that same port and intercepting them? Perhaps you started this program more than once?

Comment: once I start program I can see 'netstat -an | grep 12514
udp6       0      0 :::12514                :::*' , I tried on more than one server

Comment: there must be something else going on that you're not showing. Start with a [mcve] so that someone else can try to reproduce the error.

Comment: Actually ...I've just fixed it, changed udp4 to udp in the code above. I noticed that mcuadros/go-syslog has just udp in the very similar func. I tried udp6 before, didn't help